# One Generic Type in Multiple Functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have multiple functions which call each other:

```js
let config;
let callback;

function setConfig(c) {
  config = {};
  for(const i of c.items) config.items[i] = getData(i);
  return {
    setCallback: (cb) => { callback = cb; }
  };
}

x.addEventListener("someEvent", () => callback(config));

// usage

setConfig({items: ["a", "b", "c"]}).setCallback(function myCallback(config) {
  console.log(config.items["a"]);
  console.log(config.items["b"]);
  console.log(config.items["c"]);
})
```

Is it possible to type this in a way that the `c` argument of `setConfig` is generic (depends on the actual config object) and then automatically infer the type of the `config` argument of `myCallback`?

I already tried to put the adding of the event listener into the `setCallback` function, so I could carry around a generic type for `setConfig`, I would like to do this in another place and also be able to modify `config`, but still keep the type inferrence.

Comment: What type are the `items` supposed to be?  What type does `getData()` return?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8xPw) work for your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate about what's missing or not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to getting this to work is Typescript's [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) operator:

```js
interface Config<ConfigItems extends object> {
  items: ConfigItems;
}

type ConfigCallback<ConfigItems extends object> = (
  config: Config<ConfigItems>
) => void;

function setConfig<ConfigItems extends object>(c: {
  items: (keyof ConfigItems)[];
}) {
  config = {
    items: {},
  };

  for (const i of c.items) config.items[i] = getData(i);
  return {
    setCallback: (cb: ConfigCallback<ConfigItems>) => {
      callback = cb;
    },
  };
}
```

Now, the config argument for `myCallback` will be inferred as:

```js
Config<{
  a: any;
  b: any;
  c: any;
}
```

Comment: Also, note that I added the `items` property when redefining the `config` object in `setConfig`